# Bartle Analysis (Sequence) Theorem 3.2.4 Proof question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm learning Analysis by myself. My proof of the theorem was different to what's written in the textbook. I wanted to know if mine was also correct.

**Theorem 3.2.4:**

If $\mathbf{X}=(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers and if ${x_n}\ge0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x=\lim(x_n) \ge 0$

**Proof:**

Assume to the contrary that $x=\lim(x_n) \lt 0$.
Since the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent, $x_n$ is bounded. Thus, there exists $M \gt 0$ such that $|x_n| \le M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\epsilon = M$. Then there exists $K$ such that $|x_n - x| <  M$ for all $n \ge K$. Thus,
$|x_n - x| <  M \Leftrightarrow x-M\lt x_n \lt x+M$. Thus, $ x > M - x_n \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow x \ge 0$. This is contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!
Unfortunately, the proof is not correct. From $x - M < x_n$ the conclusion is that $x < M - x_n$, and not the other way around.

Comment: @PedroM. I now see the error in the proof :( Thank you!

Comment: To find a correct proof, note that if "the limit" is less than $0$, then there is an $\epsilon$ such that everything  within $\epsilon$ of that value must also be less than $0$.